# I think my graphic card is not being recognized properly

Tags: acer, aspire, graphics

I own an Acer aspire 4736z and I had some problems right after installing Ubuntu. Had to put the patch for the graphic card, like to make it run as it's a basic graphic card. Now I notice it's very slow when it comes to InkScape operations and the screen is displaying a strange "refreshing" effect like it happened on CRT screens.

How do I check if my card is being recognized and running correctly?

TIA

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact graphics card model.

Comment: you can use the command `lshw -c video` to obtain info about your video card, you can also use a graphical interface thanks to the command `jockey-gtk` to manage additional drivers for your system. Please specify what you have done and what you mean with "patch".

Comment: this is what lshw -c video gave me:

  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:6120(size=8)

Comment: *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:94400000-944fffff

Comment: This is the "patch" I did for the graphic card:
Hi, what type of graphics unit do you have? I had the same problem with nvidia.
At startup, when you are going to choose the operating system that you want to boot, mark ubuntu, press E, and change the words "quiet splash" to "nomodeset", if your graphics unit is nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

The OP answered in a comment

> At startup, when you are going to choose the operating system that you want to boot, mark ubuntu, press E, and change the words "quiet splash" to "nomodeset", if your graphics unit is nvidia.